# Cordova application crashes on start

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

my cordova application (which implements the crosswalk engine) crashes on one customer device, giving me the following report:

---

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/santos10wifixx/santos10wifi:4.4.2/KOT49H/P5210XXUBNK2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 16097, tid: 16097, name: e.awenko.mobile  >>> de.awenko.mobile <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    eax 00000000  ebx 00003ee1  ecx 00003ee1  edx 00000006
    esi 0000000b  edi 00000000
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
    eip 400a3426  ebp bf969b10  esp bf9695e0  flags 00200203

backtrace:
    #00  pc 00049426  /system/lib/libc.so
    #01  pc 00000005  <unknown>
```

Since I don't have to access to his device I'm not able to reproduce this problem.

I don't know if it might help but here's a list of my installed plugins:

```
com.danielcwilson.plugins.googleanalytics 0.6.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
com.dvdbrink.cordova.indexeddb 0.1.0 "Cordova-indexedDB"
com.google.playservices 22.0.0 "Google Play Services for Android"
com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 2.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.3.1 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2 1.0.11 "File Opener2"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.1 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.10 "StatusBar"
```